# Excel SUMIF VLOOKUP matches value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have data as follows:

[image]

What I want is to fill out the **Total** cells for each currency by adding up each **Balance** cell for which the currency of the account (above) matches that currency. So in this example, cell `F6` (the total for GBP) would end up having value 12 (the sum of the HSBC balance and the Barclays balance).

I have already made several attempts, however all of them result in an error.

```
SUMIF(AccountNames, VLOOKUP(F2, AccountsWithCurrencies, 2, FALSE)="GBP", AccountBalances)
```

Where `AccountNames` refers to the range `F2:H2`, `AccountBalances` is `F3:H3`, and AccountsWithCurrencies is `B3:C5`.

I have seen various suggestions use `SUMPRODUCTS` but I cannot understand them. What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this formula:

```
=SUM($F$3:$H$3*TRANSPOSE(--($C$3:$C$5=F$5)))
```

To break it down, `$C$3:$C$5=F$5` will create a 3-item array of TRUE or FALSE, depending on whether the value in column C matches the value in F5 or not. Doing this `--($C$3:$C$5=F$5)` changes the TRUE to 1 and the FALSE to 0, so in the case of GBP, you have a 3-item array of {1;1;0}. Note that the semi-colon indicates that the array is vertical. We use `TRANSPOSE` to convert this to {1,1,0} (i.e. a horizontal array). We convert it to a horizontal array so we can multiply it by the horizontal range F3:H3.

Since the values in F3:H3 are {10,2,6}, we are then essentially doing this:

```
{10,2,6} * {1,1,0}
```

Which of course evaluates to {10,2,0}. Wrapping that with the SUM function gives you the correct result for GBP.

[image]

Comment: This must be an Array formula, otherwise return #VALUE error !

Comment: Not necessarily

Comment: Thanks for the help, your answer perfectly solved the given problem, however I made the mistake of oversimplifying. Please check out the [new thread](https://superuser.com/questions/1582030/excel-sumif-account-currency-matches-the-one-being-counted)!

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($C$3:$C$5=F5)*($B$3:$B$5=$F$2:$H$2)*$F$3:$H$3)
```

[image]