# Excel SUMIF account currency matches the one being counted

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

This is related to a [previous question](https://superuser.com/questions/1581590/excel-sumif-vlookup-matches-value/1581927#1581927.) I asked. There, I made the mistake of oversimplifying in the example I used.

In contrast to that example, where each account balance appears once and in order, in reality there are many un-ordered deposits to deal with:

[image]

As mentioned before, I have already made several attempts, however all of them result in an error.

```
SUMIF(DepositAccounts, VLOOKUP(F2, AccountsWithCurrencies, 2, FALSE)="GBP", DepositAmounts)
```

Where `DepositAccounts` refers to `E3:E7`, AccountsWithCurrencies to `B3:C5` and DepositAmounts to `F3:F7`.

What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

Use SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT($F$3:$F$7*(VLOOKUP($E$3:$E$7,B:C,2,FALSE)=H3))
```

[image]

Comment: This works great! I would like to apply it to the entire columns E and F, to allow for future entry of deposits. How do I prevent the `#N/A` error?

Comment: That is a different question than the one above.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are other ways, but you can use this:

```
=SUM(SUMIF(deposits[Account],FILTER(accounts[Account],accounts[Currency]=$H3),deposits[Deposit]))
```

The important thing here is that if you want to add more accounts or more deposits, format those lists as Tables. Put your cursor in the list and press Ctrl+T, then use the Table Design tab to name the table. I've named them accounts (B2:C5) and deposits (E2:F7). As new rows are added, the formula above will always pick them up.

[image]